# How to download files to the client？

Tags: php, download

Problem Description：Here's a file, http://www.demo.com/demo.zip, how users can through the website:  demo.zip to download this file to user's computer ? How to write this download.php, thank you very much

For some reason, I do not want the user to know the real download address so that only the user can click on a download button in this download.php page, users can download the demo.zip files, and how to do? Thanks

Comment: Have you made any effort to come up with a code so others can assist if its not working?

Comment: link to the zip file and get the specified extension to be and use htaccess to enable to file type to be downloaded http://www.timewasters-place.com/how-to-force-file-downloading-with-htaccess/

Comment: For some reason, I do not want the user to know the real download address so that only the user can click on a download button in this download.php page, users can download the demo.zip files, and how to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at fpassthru: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php
You can write a file "download.php" which is called with a parameter to determine the file, check for rights to download inside and then pass the file to download to the user.